# Чем отличается активный объект от других объектов класса?

Tags: java

Прошу помощи по языку Java. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Активный объект (active object) – объект, имеющий собственный поток управления.

**Дополнено**.

> Активный объект не существует в рамках другого объекта. Он может быть создан в результате действия другого объекта, но после этого становится совершенно независимым. Создать активный объект может и пассивный, и активный объект. Активным объектом управляют события. Операции, проводимые с ним другими объектами, должны быть реализованы в виде событий вызова.
> Пассивный объект может быть создан как часть действия, совершаемого другим объектом. У пассивного объекта есть свое собственное адресное пространство; потока управления у него нет. Операции пассивного объекта вызываются внутри стека фреймов активного объекта. Пассивный объект можно моделировать при помощи конечного автомата - это позволит показать изменения его состояния, вызванные операциями над ним.

Comment: Очень общий ответ. Привели бы какие-то примеры создания и использования тех и других.

Comment: Да вроде и так понятно описано. По крайней мере тем, кто часто пишет на java.

Comment: Активно пишу на Java, но с названиями "активный" и "пассивный" объект встречаюсь впервые. Хотелось бы больше конкретики.

Comment: To @LinuxFan  Бывает, что вопросы задают люди, которые не очень хорошо знакомы с предметом. Обычно им хочется увидеть понятные ответы.